# Assigning current JPanel to new instance of JPanel but does not refresh

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, repaint

I have sub-classed JPanel to provide a generic JPanel container that contains options for a filter selected from a JComboBox.

When the JComboBox is changed from one filter to another, I have a switch statement that checks which filter is now selected and reassigns the "options" JPanel to a new instance of the options class associated with that filter:

```
public void setFilterOptions(String choice){
    switch(choice){
        case "Gaussian": options = new GaussianFilterOptions();break;
        case "Sobel": options = new SobelFilterOptions();System.out.println("?");break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the JPanel "options" does not get refreshed in the GUI after setFilterOptions is called. Whichever filter is set to show by default appears upon startup and remains even if I switch the JComboBox selection. I have tried repainting, revalidating, and validating "options" as well as the JPanel containing "options" and the JFrame enclosing the entire application.

I added print statements in each case to verify that they were working when the combo box is switched and not falling through, so I'm sure that is not the problem.

Comment: I fixed it by removing the component at the top of setFilterOptions then adding it after the switch statement and revalidating/repainting.

Comment: Please see edit to answer. CardLayout is a cleaner way to fix this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"CardLayout is a cleaner way to fix this."* It will also make the GUI `pack()` to the size it needs to display a width as wide as the widest of the panels, and a height as tall as the tallest. This is a benefit to adding all the cards to a card layout at start-up (though it might not matter in a card layout in which every panel will be the same size - though I suspect that is rare).

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's also one of the reasons I like it

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing variable with object. You have likely originally placed a JPanel object that options referred to into your GUI, but understand, *you didn't place the options variable into the GUI*, but rather (and again) *the JPanel object that it referred to* into the GUI.

If later you change the JPanel that the options variable refers to, this will have ***no effect on the GUI***, since it still holds the same original JPanel *object* that it held before. If you want to change the JPanel displayed, you have to do that directly by swapping out JPanels in the GUI. This is best accomplished by using a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapPanels extends JPanel {
    private static final String GAUSSIAN = "Gaussian";
    private static final String SOBEL = "Sobel";
    private static final String[] FILTER_OPTIONS = {GAUSSIAN, SOBEL};
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardHolderPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    private JPanel gaussianPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel sobelPanel = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox<String> filterCombo = new JComboBox<>(FILTER_OPTIONS);

    public SwapPanels() {
        JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        comboPanel.add(filterCombo);
        filterCombo.addActionListener(new ComboListener());

        gaussianPanel.add(new JLabel("Gaussian Filtering Done Here"));
        sobelPanel.add(new JLabel("Sobel Filtering Done Here"));
        cardHolderPanel.add(gaussianPanel, GAUSSIAN);
        cardHolderPanel.add(sobelPanel, SOBEL);
        int gap = 50;
        cardHolderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardHolderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class ComboListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String key = (String) filterCombo.getSelectedItem();
            cardLayout.show(cardHolderPanel, key);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwapPanels mainPanel = new SwapPanels();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwapPanels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could do it like this instead of the switch

```
public void setFilterOptions(String choice){
    options = (choice.equals("Gaussian"))? new GaussianFilterOptions():
                                           new SobelFilterOptions();  
    }
}
```